# Which is the best way to scale pixel art games with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pixel, scaling, resolution

Sprites displays like in the image but I would like them to display bigger (without blurring the pixel art).
I scaled the Sprites inside enemy and player class *(using `pygame.transform.scale()`)*, and I tried it but I for sure there's another solution more efficient to that problem; like putting everything in a surface and then scaling the whole surface instead of scaling each element separately.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


while(True):
  player.update()   #updates the character position

  enemy.update()


  # draw
  player_list.draw(screen) #draw player
  enemy_list.draw(screen) #draw enemy


  #pygame.transform.scale(surface, (1,1))
  screen.blit(update_fps(), (10,0))

  pygame.display.flip()
```

which is the best aproach to this problem?

[image: Game window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came with a solution:

To anyone wanting to make a pixel art this may be useful:

If you made a pixel art it would probably display like this
[image: the problem, the scale]

It doesn't matter how many pixels your pixel art has (by the way I recommend using Libre Sprite) just using **pygame.transform.scale(surface, (x,y))** where x and y are the dimensions of the screen (in my case screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 360)) ) should draw perfectly scaled your pixel art, like this:

[image: Correct one]

Answer (score 0):

Use either [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) or [`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) to scale the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) objects:

```py
scaled_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(image, (new_width, new_height))
```

Comment: @SavannahMadison Ye of course, because of  that it is names "smoothscale". Alternatively you can use `pygame.transform.scale`, which has the same interface.